# Difference between contains and equal(==)

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a Dictionary property

```
 public Dictionary<string, bool> SearchType { get; set; }
```

this Dictionary has 4 keys and 4 values for that keys. Now I take them to a variable from SearchType, if the values are true

```
var searchTypes = searchDetail.SearchType.Where(x => x.Value == true).ToList();
```

Here I checked the key is CKBinstituteType or CKBstate and etc, from the below code

```
foreach (var searchType in searchTypes)
{
    if (searchType.Key.Contains("CKBinstituteType"))
    {

    }
    if (searchType.Key.Contains("CKBstate"))
    {

    }
    if (searchType.Key.Contains("CKBlocation"))
    {

    }
    if (searchType.Key.Contains("CKBdistance"))
    {

    }
 }
```

or tried with this way (used equal operation instead of contains)

```
foreach (var searchType in searchTypes)
{
    if (searchType.Key == "CKBinstituteType")
    {

    }
    if (searchType.Key == "CKBstate")
    {

    }
    if (searchType.Key == "CKBlocation")
    {


    }
    if (searchType.Key == "CKBdistance")
    {

    }                   
}
```

What is the difference between of them? Which one is good for my situation? (like performance, code standard,etc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the different between of them?

Both,  `Contains` and `Equals` are using string comparison. Since your `Key` is of type string, `Contains` will check if the passed parameter is part of the key, whereas `Equals` compares  the complete string for equality.

> Which one is good for my situation? (like performance, code
>   standard,etc)

Use **[`ContainsKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method** , instead of string equals or contains. 
Contains and Equals are used inside the `foreach` loop, where you are comparing the `Key` which is a `string`  with `Contains` and `Equals`. You **don't need to iterate each item** in the dictionary. If you are trying to access it through Key, It is about doing a Linear search with complexity of `O(n)` vs doing dictionary lookup with complexity `O(1)`

You can use `ContainsKey` Like

```
if (SearchType.ContainsKey("CKBinstituteType"))
{
}
```

Currently you are converting your Dictionary to List, I am not sure if there is really a need your dictionary to a List and then do a linear search. If you really have to filter out the Dictionary based on `true` values then project the result set into a dictionary and then use `ContainsKey` like:

```
var searchTypes = searchDetail.SearchType.Where(r => r.Value == true)
                            .ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.Value);
if (searchTypes.ContainsKey("CKBinstituteType"))
{

}
if (searchTypes.ContainsKey("CKBstate"))
{

}
if (searchTypes.ContainsKey("CKBlocation"))
{


}
if (searchTypes.ContainsKey("CKBdistance"))
{

}
```

Comment: Yeap that is best option.

Comment: @user256103, I believe you are trying to use it inside a loop, there is no need to perform linear search on dictionary, instead search for the key in your Dictionary `SearchTypes`

Comment: @Habib error is `'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,bool>' does not contain a definition for 'ContainsKey' and no extension method 'ContainsKey' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,bool>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @user256103, why you are converting your dictionary to a List ?

Comment: Because the key's and values coming from user, So the count is changing. sometime 3 or 4 or 2 and the value is false ..etc.. So i converted that to list

Comment: @user256103, Instead of converting it to a `List`, convert it to a dictionary. Not really sure if it will give you a performance gain with a only 4 elements in the dictionary, but that is What I will do for following best practices. I have added the code

Comment: But Always getting the same error dude when i did't remove for loop. Is foreach want or wont?

Comment: @user256103, just copy paste the code in the last part of the answer. I am not sure why you are getting the error, You shouldn't. There is not generic collection of `KeyValuePair` in my code.

Comment: @user256103, no you don't need `foreach`, what is the **point of having `Dictionary` if you are going to do a Linear Search**.

Comment: okay cool. Now that is working. So `ContainsKey` batter than contains and equal? It's okay. Why it's better than those?

Comment: @user256103, `Contains` and `Equals` are used inside the `foreach` loop. You don't need to iterate each item in the dictionary. If you are trying to access it through `Key`, It is about doing a Linear search with complexity of `O(n)`, vs doing dictionary lookup with complexity `O(1)`

Comment: @Habib , I understood. and please update your answer with your last comment.  I hops It's helpful to other's. Thanks

Comment: @user256103, I have updated the answer, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that

```
stringExpr.Contains("CKBinstituteType")
```

checks if there is some substring of `stringExpr` which is equal to `"CKBinstituteType"`, while

```
stringExpr == "CKBinstituteType"
```

checks if `stringExpr`itself is equal to `"CKBinstituteType"`.

In both cases an ordinal comparison (which is culture invariant) is used. As an explicit example

```
"xyzxyzCKBinstituteTypexyzxyzxyz".Contains("CKBinstituteType")
```

is `true` while

```
"xyzxyzCKBinstituteTypexyzxyzxyz" == "CKBinstituteType"
```

is `false`.

---

Performance: `stringExpr.Contains("CKBinstituteType")` will be slower than `stringExpr == "CKBinstituteType"`. Note that I am not addressing the fact that these strings are keys in a `Dictionary<string, Something>`. See Habib's answer. A `Dictionary<,>` offers fast (O(1)) lookup on key. You don't utilize that when you do `dict.Where(x => criterion).ToList()`.

Comment: But my key is not inside of some other text, it is a constant string. So why Contains(). But doubt with performance

Comment: @user256103 `"abc".Contains("abc")` is still true because the "improper" substring consisting of the entire string is considered a substring.

Answer (score 0):

`contains()` checks for a sub string , where as `equals()` checks for whole string , and other difference is , `contains()` takes object of CharSequence class where as `equals()` takes Object as its parameter

Comment: Now you can decide which one you want to use.

Comment: true if the value parameter occurs within this string, or if value is the empty string (""); otherwise, false.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding simply whether using Compare or Equals on *equivalent strings* makes any difference:

Using ReSharper to see the source code for Compare, the first thing it does is

```
if ((Object)strA == (Object)strB) 
{ 
    return 0;
}
```

So it looks like they would essentially be the same for equivalent strings.

As far as performance, [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2010/09/22/whats-faster-string-equals-or-string-compare/) discusses the difference, although the comments include the most useful comparisons. Most commentators seemed to find negligible difference even after running them in very large loops. The last comment though shows a large difference between Equals and Contains and makes me wonder why the results didn't more closely mirror the others.